# Пишу бота для анонимок, не знаю как доделать одну команду

Tags: python, вконтакте, бот

Пишу бота для анонимных сообщений в ВК, хочу сделать команду, что бы они отправлялись, но не понимаю как её сделать.

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from colorama import init
init()

ivantok = 'тут токен'
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=ivantok)
ivan = vk.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.text == 'анонимка':
            if event.from_user:
                a = event.user_id
                ivan.messages.send(user_id=event.text,message=event.text,random_id=0)
```

Comment: Что значит анонимных? Есть информация о том, что ВКонтакте поддерживает подобный функционал? Я не доктор, но выглядит сомнительно и как раздолье для всякого рода спама

Comment: Как я понимаю под анонимностью подразумевается отправка сообщений от лица группы? Или что?

Comment: Clark Devlin, от аккаунта